# How to package javascript code for others to use

Tags: javascript, package

What is the best way to encapsulate some javascript such that other people can add it to their projects without having to worry about clobbering variables etc.? I had a look at the jQuery source to see how it is done; it seems like they just attach everything to the `window` object at the end. So, is the preferred way to do something like:

```
(function(w) {
    // constructor
    var MyCode = function() {
       // my code
    }
    w.MyCode = MyCode;
}(window));
```

How else can I segment my code and allow it to be plugged into other peoples existing code safely?

Comment: Create namespaces and use module pattern

Comment: It may be worth taking a look at http://requirejs.org. The library itself is designed to solve the problem of module loading in js, but the docs give some good insights into how to design the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if your variables are declared inside of function don't worry: they are already encapsulated.
2. if you use some global variables and you really need it (don't know why you should need them) - create an object with some unrepeatable name and put all the variables inside,

like

```
 var myobjectsdfjhgsdfjhgdsfjhgkjfgnalkcnkabvakbvkjladfv = { myGlobal1: "1", ... }
```

**EDIT**

ok, some new requirements...

To **let** user reuse your variables create a class/object:

```
function myClass() {
  this.myVariableToShare = 1;

  this.myMethod = function() {
    this.myVariableToShare ++;
  }
}

var myObjectOfMyClass = new myClass();
```

and then you can say to user: "Hey, use this object!". And he can do so:

```
alert(myObjectOfMyClass.myVariableToShare);
```

or

```
myObjectOfMyClass.myMethod();
alert(myObjectOfMyClass.myVariableToShare);
```

This is how the libraries are usually implemented.

You can do another way as well: just create a list of global variables in the beginning of your code:

```
var myVariable = 1;
```

and then it is visible in every function (of course if it does not have a variable like that inside). But I prefer the object because you have everything inside of one package and user is not afraid to use the names he wants for his variables.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I have everything encapsulated in a function, that's fine, I was more wondering how to give the user access to the code since it is encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing a Jquery Plugin if you wanted your library to work with JQuery.

Here is the official guide. http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/